# How to extract series of numbers from string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

A  string is given

```
st=arr{12 13 5 10 4}
```

Is it possible to extract all numbers from it?

```
li=[12,13,5,10,4]
```

I have tried `re` but failed.

Comment: What is `arr{12 13 5 10 4}`? Is that surrounded by quotes? is that a string? Did you try anything to solve this? Unfortunately, someone just dumped an answer, but next time please put together a more coherent question that falls within the example of a [mcve]

Comment: @idjaw tbh, it doesn't matter how does it look. He said it's a string. Whether it has a prefix, a suffix, just random stuff surrounding it, `\d` will always work.

Comment: @Bharel For the sake of being explicit and accurate with an example that illustrates a problem, then it absolutely does matter how it looks like. The point is not to be the FGITW here in who can maybe interpret the question the fastest, but to ensure that the question is coherent and a realistic/correct example of what is trying to be solved. Maybe your solution is fine, sure. But, why not help improve the question and find out 100% what is being asked in what way before just throwing an answer down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list(map(int, re.findall(r"\d+", st)))`

Comment: That's specifically discouraged in the introduction of iterators for `map`, etc.: https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists

Comment: @jonrsharpe he wants a list. I would also be better off without it being a list. Leaving it as an iterator would be ideal but he might want double iteration in which case this will be a better approach

Comment: That's fine, my point is that `list(map(...))` should be rewritten as a list comprehension.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it's discouraged because people often use lambda which makes it ugly as hell. I'm not using a lambda here, so no problem. In fact, this will actually be faster and is rather clear. No real difference anyhow.

Comment: It's not faster, but if you think it's clearer fair enough.

Comment: It's a rather premature optimization but it's 1.47 msec to 1.82 msec for a range of 9999 which means 20% faster. Really doesn't matter though. Clearness is what matters and I believe it's up to preference :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
st="12 13 5 10 4 ftg"
numbers = re.findall(r"[0-9]+", st)
print (numbers)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, whose only clear part was that the OP wants to obtain a list of integers. You only produced a list of strings.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming every number in your string are separated by a whitespace, the easiest way to do this is probably by using list comprehensions

`[int(number) for number in st.split(" ")]`

If your string is 
 `st = "12 13 5 10 4"`
the code will do two things

- **`st.split(" ")`** will create the list

  > ["12", "13", "5", "10", "4"]
- **`int(number)`** will be applicated to every element of the above list. So every string will be converted to an int. You'll obtain

  > [12, 13, 5, 10, 4]

Comment: The OP's example, though unclear, contradicts your assumption that numbers are separated by spaces. See the first and last one...

Comment: In his example ( {12 13 5 10 4} ) every number are separated by spaces. Sure, there are no whitespace before the first and after the last number, but between two numbers there is always a space. And my code work for his example and every other constructed on the same model.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Splitting on spaces will return `'4}' for the last item, for example.